# Extract common info in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['This here is text',{1:10,2:20}],['My Text was here',{2:5,3:30}],['This was not ready',{5:9,1:2}]]), columns=['Text','Other info'])
              Text      Other info
0   This here is text  {1: 10, 2: 20}
1    My Text was here   {2: 5, 3: 30}
2  This was not ready    {1: 2, 5: 9}
```

I need to find common terms between each pair of rows and reduce the dictionaries as well, like this

```
row1 row2    common_text     other_info
  0    1        here,text      {2 : 25}
  0    2        this           {1 : 12}
  1    2        was            {}
```

Is there any pythonic way to do this instead of splitting each pair of rows and comparing ? I mean since I will be finding Also, my data is large (>20000) rows so I would appreciate any help for faster solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is take the text from each row, split that into words and use the words and the row number to fill a new `defaultdict(list)` with the word as the key and the line number as data.

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict

In [2]: rows = ['This here is text', 'My Text was here', 'This was not ready']

In [3]: where = defaultdict(list)

In [4]: for n, line in enumerate(rows):  # A mockup for the pandas table.
   ...:     for word in line.split():
   ...:         where[word.lower()].append(n)
   ...:         

In [5]: where
Out[5]: 
defaultdict(list,
            {'here': [0, 1],
             'is': [0],
             'my': [1],
             'not': [2],
             'ready': [2],
             'text': [0, 1],
             'this': [0, 2],
             'was': [1, 2]})
```

In a larger dataset you would find words in more than two rows.
But using the list of line numbers, you can easily make all possible combinations to two lines using `permutations`:

```
In [6]: from itertools import permutations

In [7]: list(permutations([1,3,7], 2))
Out[7]: [(1, 3), (1, 7), (3, 1), (3, 7), (7, 1), (7, 3)]
```

As the final step, you can merge the dictionaries from the original dataframe.